# how to use signalR push notification on asp.net MVC data from API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

why doesn't my datatable change immediately? must be refreshed first. I've been looking for it but haven't found the right solution yet.
when running, a message appears on the console, the connection is successful, then the connection is lost. like I'm confused how to implement the correct one. please help me

hub

```
public class TransactionHub: Hub
{
    
}
```

Repository

```
private readonly IHubContext<TransactionHub> _context;
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
private readonly string BASE_URL;

public TransactionRepository(IConfiguration configuration, IHubContext<TransactionHub> context) 
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        BASE_URL = _configuration["BaseUrl"];
        _context = context;
    }

 public async Task<List<Transaction>> GetAllTransaction(string token)
    {
        var transaction = new List<Transaction>();
        var apiUrl = BASE_URL + "/Transaction";
        var response = await RequestGet(ClientBase(token), apiUrl);
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var jsonDeserializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
            };
            var apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse<List<Transaction>>>(result, jsonDeserializeSettings);
            transaction = apiResponse.data;
        }

        await _context.Clients.All.SendAsync("refreshTransactions");

        return transaction;
    }
```

Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllTransaction()
    {
        List<Transaction> transactions = await _transactionRepository.GetAllTransaction("token");
        var jsonData = Json(new
        {
            data = transactions
        });
        return jsonData;
    }
```

javascript

```
$(() => {
let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/transactionhub").build()

connection.start()

connection.on("refreshTransactions", function () {
    loadData()
})

loadData();

function loadData() {
    let table = $('#transactionList').DataTable({
        "pagingType": "simple",
        "autoWidth": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/GetAllTransaction",
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json",
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "email", "autoWidth": true, "searchable": true },
            { "data": "stationName", "autoWidth": true, "searchable": true },
        ],
    });
})
```

startup

```
services.AddSignalR();
endpoints.MapHub<TransactionHub>("/transactionhub");
```

Comment: SignalR 2.1 adds an overload to the server OnDisconnect event that indicates if the client deliberately disconnected rather than timing out. The StopCalled parameter is true if the client explicitly closed the connection. In JavaScript, if a server error led the client to disconnect, the error information will be passed to the client as $.connection.hub.lastError.For details, please refer to the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events